# load a page when close a popup page using "beforeunload"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach an event hanldler to `beforeunload` in javascript. Here is my code:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {

    $("#popupin1").load("new.html");
})
```

I get the alert but the loading div is not happen. Is it possible to call a function on closing a page (popup page) in this way?

Comment: No it's not possible in this manner - the window will be unloaded before the AJAX call completes. It seems very odd to load new content in to a page that's about to be unloaded anyway. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ok ,i have two pages 
1.mypage.html
2.newpopup.html
i create a table in newpopup.html and load it in mypage.html. 
and i have a popupbutton. when i click this button a newpopup.html page is shown .and hide the table in mypage.html.
.my requrement is when close this popup page i want to show the popupin1 div .that i hide early in my main page(mypage.html)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the answer .by done some change in this same code

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {

  window.opener.$("#popupin1").load("new.html");
})
```

also need

window.opener